# how to pass string as variable actionscript 2

Tags: string, variables, actionscript-2

Say I have these variables

```
var word1 ='wordA';
var word2 ='wordB';
var word3 ='wordC';
var word4 ='wordD';
var word5 ='wordE';
```

and I have this loop

```
for (var i=1; i<6; i++) {
    // make word + i = ''; (an empty string)
}
```

how would I go about doing so using Actionscript 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `this`:

```
for (var i=1; i<6; i++) {
    this[ "word" + i ] = ''; (an empty string)
}
```

Comment: Ah, it works. I normally code in Javascript and use $(this) when using Javascript selectors, I find it strange that 'this' in actionscript can be used this way. Interesting.. anyways, thanks.